# Login to facebook in java code and get token

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, access-token

I'm trying to write a program that can go through my details and other's in facebook. for that I used restfb api for facebook, but up until now I logged in to facebook and got my acces token manually.
Is there a way to do this by code?
I dont know how to send url request if its needed for my request.

Thank you!!

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/v2.2

Answer (score -1):

[oAuth2](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/) is what you're looking for

Comment: I think i need to create an app for that, but i need to get facebook to approve, dont i?

Comment: Don't know their current policy, just try, it's anyway for free.